# How to set a message in JQuery Validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using JQuery Validate, I can set easily messages when something goes wrong:

```
<input class="required" id="pwd" name="pwd" type="password" title="ERROR here" />
```

How can I make this the default message when there is no error and set another message when there is an error? Example:

```
<input class="required" id="pwd" name="pwd" type="password" title="Write your password" />
....

$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        pwd: {
          SET MESSAGE IF ERROR
        }
    }
});
```

Edit: I'll try to explain better: I need first no message, when the user sets focus to an input I want to show a "status" message (like "Write your password") and last, if the text is wrong, show an error message (like "enter more than 8 characters").

Answer (score 1):

Ok try this:

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        pwd: {
          $('label[for=pwd]').html('ERROR HERE');
        }
    }
});
```

I don't know what plugin you're using for the validation but this is how you would update a label assigned to that input field.

Comment: No, what I want is to show a message ("write your password") when the user puts focus in my input field and put another message if the field don't validate ("you must write at least 8 characters" or "this field is mandatory").

Comment: Where do you want to show it? Do you have a div container setup for these messages, or do you want an alert?

Comment: Sorry, I'll explain better.. By default, JQuery validate shows the parsing errors in a label. This is ok for me. My problem is that I want to show a message if there is no error (while user is typing) and change this message if user clicks on submit and there is a validation error. It's ok also if the first message is hiden when the input loses the focus.